# How to import a Matrix from a text file in Python

Tags: python, import, matrix, numpy, load

Hey this might be a simple question, but I have never had to import any files into Python before.

So I have a numpy Matrix in a text file, named `dmatrix.txt`, so how would I be able to import the file into Python and use the matrix?

I am trying to use `numpy.load()`, but I am unsure how to use it.

Comment: How did you create that file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [`numpy.loadtxt('dmatrix.txt')`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html); you could add a `delimiter` argument if the file is comma-separated or something.

[`numpy.load`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html) is for files in numpy/python binary formats - created by [`numpy.save`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html), [`numpy.savez`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html), or [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html).

Comment: Is there a specific way to call the text file?
I am getting an error:


Traceback (most recent call last):


    np.loadtxt('dmatrix.txt')



    fh = iter(open(fname, 'U'))



IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dmatrix.txt'

Comment: Give a relative path from python's working directory, i.e. the directory you're running python from, which you could see by `print os.getcwd()`.