# Creating a Matrix in Python3 with 1643 dimensions

Tags: python, matrix

I'm reading in a large data file providing the matrix data.

```
import re

matrix_dimension = 1643
file1 =  open('7b-2.txt', "r")
flatMatrix = file1.readline()
file1.close()

numbers = re.compile("-?\d+")
result = list(map(float, numbers.findall(flatMatrix)))

matrix = []
for row in range(matrix_dimension) :
    a = []
    for column in range(matrix_dimension) : 
        a.append(float(result.pop(0)))
    matrix.append(a)
```

But its getting stuck at the popping the first element in the result of the flatmatrix list. Is there another way to build up unusually large matrices?

Comment: not sure you're using the word dimension correctly https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320676/what-is-the-dimension-of-a-matrix. For instance a tic-tac-toe board would have 2 dimensions

Comment: what does 7b-2.txt look like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import a Matrix from a text file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905899/how-to-import-a-matrix-from-a-text-file-in-python)

Comment: How many elements, in total, do you think the result should have, and how did you calculate that result? And what exactly do you mean by "getting stuck", and how did you determine that this is happening?

Comment: 2250000 elements using len().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using NumPy:

```
import re
import numpy as np

matrix_dimension = 1643
with open('7b-2.txt', 'r') as f:
    flat_matrix = f.read()

numbers = re.compile("-?\d+")
result = list(map(float, numbers.findall(flat_matrix)))
matrix = np.array(result).reshape((matrix_dimension, matrix_dimension))
```

A float64 is like 8 bytes. So, for a 1643 × 1643  matrix, it would be around ~22 MB in memory (1643 x 1643 x 8 / 1000000), not actually that large in the grand scheme of things.

Note if the file just has numbers with a separator between them e.g., a space you can use, `np.fromstring` instead of the regex potentially:

```
result = np.fromstring(flat_matrix, sep=' ')
```

Comment: I tried your code, and got the error: `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2250000 into shape (1643,1643)`

Comment: The error indicates a mismatch between the data size and the specified dimensions. For a 1643×1643 matrix, you should have 
2699449
(1643×1643= 2699449) elements.

Check your data file to ensure you have the correct number of elements. After reading and parsing the file, you may also want to validate len(result) to confirm it matches the expected size.

Comment: I'm sqrt'ing the len(result) to get the dimensions now. After running this line: `matrixA = np.array(result).reshape((matrix_dimension, matrix_dimension))
print(result)` I get this: `[-1 -8  5 ...  7  8 -4]`

Comment: `matrixA = np.array(result).reshape(matrix_dimension, matrix_dimension)` does the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Use [numpy.loadtxt](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html):

```py
from io import StringIO   # StringIO behaves like a file object
c = StringIO("0 1\n2 3")
np.loadtxt(c)

# array([[0., 1.],
#       [2., 3.]])
```

Don't reinvent the wheel